# Best way to store and update package data as a dev in R?

Tags: r, package, r-package

I'm developing a package that needs to store and manipulate data in the background over the course of an R session. Primarily, this will be a data frame about what the user has downloaded so far, updating as they download more, etc.  This data will be used my many of the functions in my package, for example, to see if they need to download anything else.  I expect that in some cases, this data frame might become relatively large (thousands of rows).

I know that one easy way of storing global variables for packages is to use store them as options with the `option()` function.  I can also imagine calling a stateful function at the beginning of each session, which would serve as the gateway for this data.

But I generally get the feeling that options are generally meant to be pretty small in size, and that stateful functions seem like they might get confusing and requires some work to get operating smoothly. **Is there a better way to store information like this?**  If it helps, I dont want the user to be able to directly manipulate the package data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store dataframes in the `/data` folder of the package.

As explained [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html), each dataset should be stored in a `.RData` file containing only one object, having the same name, and created by the `save` command.

As exported functions, data objects should be documented. One possibility is to create a Roxygen .R script in `/R` folder with the `@format` tag to describe the content of the dataset, and to end this script by `"DataSetName"`

```
#' My data set
#'
#' some useful data
#'
#' @format a dataframe with 464 rows and 2 variables
#' * bar : bar name
#' * foo : foo value
#'
#' @source created by me 
"DataSetName"
```

[EDIT] If you want to store data for the package in the current Session, you can create an hidden environment for the package in one of the package's .R scripts :

```
.pkg.env <- new.env()

#' Set hidden variable
#'
#' @param var 
#'
#'

pkg.set <- function(var) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
  if (exists(varname,env=parent.frame())) {
    assign(deparse(substitute(var)),var,env=.pkg.env)}
  else {
    stop(paste(varname,"doesn't exist"))
  }
}

#' get hidden variable
#'
#' @param var 
#'
#'

pkg.get <- function(var) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(var))
  .pkg.env[[varname]]
}
```

Both functions aren't exported, so that users don't see them.
Nevertheless, you can use them between your package's functions:

```
TempData <- data.frame(test="Test")
pkg.set(TempData)
pkg.get(TempData)
  test
1 Test
```

Comment: For the use case that I meant, the data is not saved between R sessions, is completely dependent on the user, and needs to be in memory at all times.  I don't think constantly reading and writing the data to file makes sense.